# Исключение из выделение текста на странице JS

Tags: javascript

Прошу помочь, есть код, который добавляет к выделению со страницы слово "Подробнее" и ссылку на сайт. Но нужно сделать исключение, если например пользователь выделяет заголовок (h1), то прописывать ссылку не нужно. Как это реализовать?

```js
function addLink() {

  var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var selection;
  selection = window.getSelection();
  var pagelink = "<br \/><br \/> Подробнее: <a href='" + document.location.href + "'>" + document.location.href + "<\/a>"; // В этой строке поменяйте текст на свой
  var copytext = selection + pagelink;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
  newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';
  body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
  newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
  selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
  }, 0);
}
document.oncopy = addLink;
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>Текст</p>
```

Comment: **...который добавляет к выделению со страницы слово "Подробнее"**. Сформулируйте пожалуйста иначе, или разъясните, а то не понял суть. Добавьте рабочий кода, который нужно будет отредактировать, что бы все заработало так, как вы хотите.

Comment: Что делать в случае если заголовок выделяется частично? либо в выделение входит не только заголовок. либо часть заголовка и часть текста?